# Incorrect extract epoch and current time

Tags: postgresql-9.5

Here table
[image]

column **states** is jsonb.

Example of states (json)

```
[
    {
        "dt": "2020-12-23T16:15:18.405+00:00",
        "id": "order.new",
        "data": {}
    }
]
```

Current date is 23 Dec 2020 and current time is 20:26.

Now I want to show records with **modified_at** > 900 sec (15 min) and states->0->'id' = 'order.new'

I try this:

```
SELECT id, modified_at, states->0 as state FROM shop_order 
WHERE (states ->0 @> '{"id":"order.new"}')  
        AND (extract(epoch from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - modified_at)::integer > 900)
```

But result is empty

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps parentheses are needed around the subtraction?

Comment: Try: `and modified_at >= current_timestamp - interval '15 minute'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name "current_timestamp >= modified_at - interval '900 second' " -> will show only records where delta between current date and modified_at is more than 15 minutes?